# How to move a row in jquery datatable to top on buttonclick..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to move a row to top of datatable on a button click... i have tried with append function...but while using search function of datatable , the table is getting reset..below is a sample code of what i am trying..

```
<table id="ArgumentsTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable">

                <thead>
                    <tr role="row"><th >Name</th><th >Position</th><th >Office</th><th >Age</th> 
 <th>Start date</th><th >Salary</th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                <tr role="row" class="odd">
                        <td class="sorting_1">Airi Satou</td>
                        <td>Account <button class="btn " id="btn1" >Save</button></td>
                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                        <td>33</td>
                        <td>2008/11/28</td>
                        <td>$162,700</td>
                    </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
                        <td class="sorting_1">Angelica Ramos</td>
                        <td>Chief <button class="btn " id="btn2" >Save</button></td>
                        <td>London</td>
                        <td>47</td>
                        <td>2009/10/09</td>
                        <td>$1,200,000</td>
                    </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
                        <td class="sorting_1">Ashton Cox</td>
                        <td>Junior 
          <button class="btn " id="btn3"  >Save</button></td>
                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                        <td>66</td>
                        <td>2009/01/12</td>
                        <td>$86,000</td>
                    </tr></tbody>

                </table>
```

Here is script code i am using

```
`     $(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#ArgumentsTable').DataTable(
     {
        stateSave: true
     }
    );
  $('.btn').click( function () {
  /*var index =0;
  // rowCount = table.data().length-1,
   //var rowApp = $(this).closest('tr');
  //var indexRow = table.row(rowApp).index();
  //tempRow =""
   /*insertedRow = table.row(indexRow).data(),tempRow;
         for (var i=rowCount;i>index;i--) {
           tempRow = table.row(i-1).data();
          table.row(i).data(tempRow);
           table.row(i-1).data(insertedRow);
     } */
        $(this).closest('tr').prependTo("#ArgumentsTable");
     //table.row('.selected').remove().draw( false );
     } );
    } );`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Found a solution by addinng a hidden column id at 0th position and by sorting by its value. Thereby all the selected row will come to top by changing the id value

```
   var table = $('#ArgumentsTable').DataTable({
    paging: true,
    stateSave: true,
    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
    'drawCallback': function (settings) {
        //$('#ArgumentsTable tr:last .btn').remove();

        // Remove previous binding before adding it
        $('.btn').unbind('click');

        // Bind clicks to functions
        $('.btn').click(moveRow);

    }
});


function moveRow() {
    var row = $(this).parents('tr');
    var index = table.row(row).index();
    //alert(index)
    var data1 = table.row(index).data();
    //console.log(data1);
    data1[0] = -data1[0];
    console.log(data1[0]);
    table.row(index).data(data1).draw();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented one sample application where we have disabled pagination, sorting and searching for the jQuery datatable and added the grid drag drop as well as select the grid row and move it to up, down, top and bottom easily. Give one button to read the data from the datatable using jQuery for each loop. Hope this sample example will help you.

Please check demo

```js
function ReadSortData() {
    $('#example>tbody').find('tr').each(function () {
        var textval = $(this).find('td').text(); // this will be the text of each <td>
        console.log(textval)
    });
}
// Move up or down (depending...)
function moveRow(direction) {

    //Find selected rows
    var row = $('#example').find('.selected'); //$(this).parents('tr');
    
    if (row.length === 0) {
        alert('Please select row.');
        return;
    }

    if (direction == "Up") {
        row.insertBefore(row.prev());
    } else if (direction == "Down") {
        row.insertAfter(row.next());
    } else if (direction == "Top") {
        row.insertBefore($("#example > tbody tr:first"));
    } else {
        row.insertAfter($("#example > tbody tr:last"));
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "ordering": false,
        "searching": false,
        paging: false
    });

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        } else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });


    $("#example tbody").sortable({
        start: function (e, ui) {
            var elements = ui.item.siblings('.selected.hidden').not('.ui-sortable-placeholder');
            ui.item.data('items', elements);
        },
        update: function (e, ui) {
            ui.item.after(ui.item.data("items"));
        },
        stop: function (e, ui) {
            ui.item.siblings('.selected').removeClass('hidden');
            $('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.13/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.13/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button id="btnUp" onclick="moveRow('Up')">Move Up</button>
<button id="btnDown" onclick="moveRow('Down')">Move Down</button>
<button id="btnTop" onclick="moveRow('Top')">Move Top</button>
<button id="btnBottom" onclick="moveRow('Bottom')">Move Bottom</button>
<button id="btnGetSortData" onclick="ReadSortData()">Get Data</button>
<table id="example" class="display table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Tiger 1</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>11</td>
                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Garrett 22</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>22</td>
               
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Ashton 33</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>33</td>
                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Donna 44</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>44</td>
               
            </tr>
            
        </tbody>
        
    </table>
```

Thanks,
Ashish J.

Comment: This is good, but is it possible with search and pagination also?